# Разноцветные многострочные комментарии в QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

В QTextEdit надо задавать блоки текста

```
[строка
строка
строка
...]
```

т.е. подобие многострочного комментария.
Как мне выделить их разными цветами?

Пробовал через `QSyntaxHighlighter`, но пока не получилось. Буду признателен любой помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно представлять текст в виде `html-блока` и воспользоваться методом `QTextEdit.setHtml`:

```
html = '[<p style="color: red">Строка</p><p style="color:green">Строка</p>]'

text = QTextEdit()
text.setHtml(html)
```

Сами цвета можно задавать отдельно, например в gui:

```
colorP1 = 'red'
colorP2 = 'green'
html = f'[<p style="color: {colorP1}">Строка</p><p style="color:{colorP2}">Строка</p>]'

text = QTextEdit()
text.setHtml(html)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, попробую.